# Auto update text box depending on an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two input boxes here.

```
<input type="text" name="ltc">
<input type="text" name="btc" readonly>
```

Ok, now what I want is..that when I enter some value in the **first** textbox, then that value would be multiplied by a constant number and the result would be displayed in the **btc** textbox.

I guess this can be done via jQuery, but I have no idea as to how I can do it(because of my limited/no knowledge in jQuery).
Can somebody guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: It can be done with jQuery on change. Try something first and then people will help with your code. This isn't a code request site. There are PLENTY of articles on google with the keywords you have in your question.

Comment: PHP and JQuery are different, yes. But "math" is "math", any which way you slice it. It just depends "how" you slice it. ;-) Show us what you tried.

Comment: Why the PHP tag removal? Maybe the OP intended on using or is using PHP. @AndyHolmes and just didn't mention it. We can't be 100% certain. With the looks of using form inputs, it's most probable that the OP intends on using it with PHP.

Comment: Because it is better done with jQuery. The OP even mentions jQuery in the question. PHP would require either ajax or page refreshes, when you can just use $('.selector').on('change', function(){});

Comment: I agree you have a point there. I edited my comment (above) about the OP's use of form inputs. Which would require PHP, most probably (most of the time). @AndyHolmes Sure wish the OP would get in on this convo to let us know. ;-)

Comment: Form inputs don't denote the need for PHP. All of this can be achieved without php, and just jQuery. OP asks about information updating another input field; which is done with jQuery. If the OP wishes to send to email/database, then yes php will be needed, but going off the question there is no mention of PHP intentions. And yes @Fred-ii- OP needs to jump in haha

Comment: "Touché" --- @AndyHolmes cheers (which is why I wrote "most of the time") and not "all" the time. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution:

html code:

```
<input type="text" name="ltc" id="input-ltc">
<input type="text" name="btc" readonly id="input-btc">
```

javascript:

```
var inputLtc = document.getElementById('input-ltc'),
inputBtc = document.getElementById('input-btc');

var constantNumber = 2;

inputLtc.onchange = function() {
   var result = parseFloat(inputLtc.value) * constantNumber;
   inputBtc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KT4R/

edit:

You may use onkeydown to get result when typing.

Comment: This worked..could you please edit your fiddle with onkeydown?
I tried to do it..but no luck.
Thanks

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/6KT4R/1/
if this helped you consider marking it as accepted, thanks! :-)

Comment: Working perfect.
Thanks :)