# Update text box automatically when values in other text boxes are changed

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a google script which creates an html page with a variable number of text boxes and pre fills those text boxes with values.  I need a final text box that shows the sum of the values in the above text boxes.  If the user changes any of the values in the text boxes, then I need the sum to autoupdate.
Similar to this problem [Auto update text box depending on an input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926900/auto-update-text-box-depending-on-an-input-box), but I have a unknown number of input boxes.

This is the code which generates the input boxes, they are based on the range "Brew_Hops_Weight" which can vary in length.

```
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Hops</legend> 
            <? var data = getRange4("Brew_Hops").getValues(); ?>
            <? var hopWeights = getRange4("Brew_Hops_Weight").getValues(); ?>
            <table>
              <tr> <th>Hops</th> <th>Current Weight&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th> <th>Proposed Weight</th> </tr>
              <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
                <tr >
                  <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
                    <td> <input name="selector[]" class="ads_Checkbox" type="checkbox"checked /> <?= data[i][j] ?> </td>  
                    <td> <?= Math.round(hopWeights[i][j]*100)/100 ?> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" size="8" name="IBUs" value=<?= Math.round(hopWeights[i][j]*100)/100 ?>  /> <td> 
                  <? } ?>                 
                </tr>
              <? } ?>
             <tr> 
                  <td><strong>IBU</strong></td> 
                  <td><strong><?= Math.round(getRange4("Brew_IBU").getValue()) ?></strong></td> 
                  <td> <input type="text" size="8" name="IBUs" value="xx"  </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
     </fieldset>
```

Comment: Add in event handlers and use query selectors...

Comment: Shouldn't this line :`<td> <input type="text" size="8" name="IBUs" value=<?= Math.round(hopWeights[i][j]*100)/100 ?>  /> <td>` be this way: `<td> <input type="text" size="8" name="IBUs" value="<?= Math.round(hopWeights[i][j]*100)/100 ?>" /></td>`